# Cannot set packet duration when creating fragmented mp4 video files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a fragmented mp4 video file from a variable frame rate source using libavformat from ffmpeg 3.2.4.
Apparently the mp4 video file seems correct, in the sense that I can play it with VLC player with no evident problems.
Anyway, when analyzing the mp4 file with `ffprobe`, I see that the `pkt_duration` values are wrong, as they were computed for a nominal, fixed 25 fps frame rate source (where the real rtp source has a nominal value of 15 fps, and the actual frame duration values range between 40 and 80 ms).
This happens both when using `frag_custom` option (then calling `av_write_frame()` with a null packet to "close" the fragment) or using the `frag_duration` option.
Incidentally, I noted that if the mp4 file is closed before the fragment length has been reached (that is, without calling `av_write_frame()` on a null packet), the pkt_duration value is exactly what I expect.
Is there anybody having the same kind of problem ?
Thanks in advance,
Massimo Perrone